# Why does my render have a gamma value different from the viewport?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, tracking

Blender seems to be changing the movie clip gamma after rendering. What causes it and how can I fix it?

View Port:
[image: And that's how it look after rendering]

Render:
[image: And that's how it look after rendering]

Here is my [.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B39l96jiKAYsVDNMWXU3X3c3SVU) (including 10 frames of the clip).

Comment: Could you post a blend so we can examine what's wrong? Try using [Blend-exchange](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/630/announcing-blend-exchange-a-new-solution-to-blend-hosting). Remember to pack external resources too.

Comment: Should I include video clip too?

Comment: Yes, but if it's too large (say 10 Mb) you might want to somehow reduce the size (i.e. cut it to only a couple of frames).

Comment: Included 10 frames. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B39l96jiKAYsVDNMWXU3X3c3SVU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened your file, made a render, too much exposure.
I went to the compositor, turned on the  "backdrop" functions, everything went OK, even the animation rendering!

Looks like a little bug.

Comment: If this really is a repeatable bug, you should submit it to the Bug Tracker. https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/